# Saving files from Windows to WSL1 Location

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux 1 (WSL1). I have a git repo there where I develop and work on software projects. I also have MATLAB but it is installed on Windows (not on WSL1). I'd like to save files in a directory on WSL1 (e.g. `/home/USERNAME/projects/MATLAB`) while working on them via my Windows MATLAB installation.

I *think* I can map my WSL1 drive to `My Computer` on Windows and then navigate to `/home/USERNAME/projects/MATLAB` and save files that way.

But I'm wondering, is it okay to do this? Or will there be some type of file problems/conflicts/corruption, since I'm mixing Windows with WSL1. Perhaps there is a smarter way to accomplish this and if so I'd be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: NEVER mess with anything in your root filesystem outside of /mnt/x/blah.  If you need to do what you are implying, I suggest that you remove/delete the matlab folder and `ln -s` one from /mnt/c/blahblahblah in its place.  Bad juju will happen if you mess with the Linux files from the Windows side.

Comment: Right, so that is an option I've done in the past. But then the MATLAB files don't get pushed to my repo, just the links.

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  Link the entire folder, not links within the folder.. I am sure you are able to figure out what is happening here. ;-) .. Oh!! .. I feel your pain.

Comment: Oh goodness. I think I know what you are saying now. I was thinking in terms of symbolic links! Sorry for the confusion, and thank you!

Comment: Also.. I have had my ENTIRE home directory sitting on "the windows side".. the problem there comes when certain permissions can't be faked.. (via chmod).. otherwise, I myself have mapped %userprofile% to /home/<myname> and had it work.  This was very handy for ssl keys and the like ;)

Comment: If you have more problems, come back.  And you are welcome.  Hope I was able to help. :)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Am I misreading something in the use case here, or wouldn't `\\wsl$\<distroname>` still be acceptable for the OP to use to save the MATLAB files?

Comment: right you are @NotTheDr01ds .. this would be dandy.. I have a one track mind and this clearly wasn't the track. :)  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds oh - is that what I described in my original post?

Comment: Perhaps -- There are a few meanings to "mapping", so I wasn't quite sure which way you were going.  Using `\\wsl$\<distroname>` is safe; using the file structure under `%appdata%` (or any other WSL installation location) is bad.  See [this Microsoft devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) for details (although they don't mention the "other installation locations" issue.